# Bumped by Community localization issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-user, localization, russian-stackoverflow

Recently a banner, "Bumped to the homepage by Community", was created in the current form:

> **bumped to the homepage** by $community$ $when$

It leads localization problem (e.g. in Russian):

The current localized message looks like this:

> [image: Community]

because variable `$community$` unfolds into "Community ♦". In case of *Stack Overflow in Russian* it should unfold into "Дух сообщества ♦".

My request is to modify the original string to:

> **bumped to the homepage** by $RefBegin$Community ♦$RefEnd$ $when$

so that it would be possible to translate it according to the localized name of the Community ♦ user.

Comment: [Related question on ruSO.meta](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4225/176217).

Comment: Is the community user's name localised anywhere else?

Comment: @Cai yes. You can see Community user profile in [es](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad) or [pt](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade) SO.

Comment: What's weird is that it's called "Community" on [Meta Spanish SO](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) and [both](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) of [the](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) Japanese versions (they [plan](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2308) to translate the rest of the meta profile text however).

Comment: SE is written in glorious C#, not your gutter PHP language.

Comment: @Won't my language is Russian, not PHP!

Comment: HAH!  You can't fool me!  Those are PHP variables!  Admit your shame!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used a hard-coded version of the community user display name - I have now updated the code to use the correct, localized version.

With you in the next build.

Comment: Using only one form of community user's name is not flexible. E.g. in Russian language we have many cases of name according grammatic rules. So allow translator to decide would be a better variant.